# Non Public NSURLConnection leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsurlconnection

I'm getting a number of leaks in my app that are caused by using NSURLConnections. The thing is that all the leaks are system objects, not actually the objects I am creating. Things like CFURLConnection, CFURLRequest, URLConnectionInstanceData and HTTPBodyData. But the actual NSURLConnection is not reported as a leak and neither is the NSMutableURLRequest.
I'm unable to post all of the code so here's the important information:

1. The project is non ARC.
2. The NSURLConnections are created on the main thread.
3. This is an asynchronous call.
4. There are multiple NSURLConnections created all using the same delegate.
5. The call is a HTTP post
6. Have seen this bug in both 5.0 and 5.1 devices.

I've tried a number of different approaches to refactor the code and stop the problem but I really don't know how to track down the cause of the bug since everything is pointing to system libraries.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any ideas how one would go about finding where the problem lies?

Comment: Why are you unable to post the code - it would really help us find the leak :)

Comment: Company rules and such. You know how it goes

Comment: If we can't see your code, we can't tell you what you have done wrong. Paste the exact code and then clear the sensitive information.

Comment: Is the leak show using the simulator or a device -  if it's the simulator, confirm on a real device. The simulator uses a different memory model and sometimes gives false positives (and probably false negatives as well!)

Comment: Have done all my testing on a device.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused by a malformed URL. It appears that if you supply an invalid url it causes a leak in CFNetwork.